# How to change the unit

Tags: modeling

I am studing the blender sence 2021 still I don't know how to change the unit into feets or inches
Is it alabel?
we use the units as architect into feets or inches
Is it possable to change the units into feets and inches?

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Scene Properties* > *Units* > *Unit System* and switch it from *Metric* to *Imperial*. Below you will find *Length*, which is now set to *Feet*. But you can change it to *Inches*.

[image: scene units]