Changing dimensions
I am new to Blender and just learning it.  I have experience with drafting programs and I am used to being able to change dimensions of objects easily.  So far with Blender I have been unable to find a way to do this.  I know about the measure tool and the measure overlay that shows dimensions but there doesn't seem to be a way to change them other than eyeballing it with a modeling tool.  I could do some math and use the transformation percentage to change a dimension but that seems a bit complex.  Is there a simple way to change a dimension? I feel I've looked everywhere.     Thank you.

This question is similar to: How to set object dimension. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This may also be something you are missing: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292374/how-to-change-the-unit
Because by default Blender may not be functioning in real world units.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/how-to-scale-dimensions-proportionally-to-a-specific-size

@common_goldfish Blender by default uses metric units. My answer which you linked to explains how to switch from metric to imperial... or did you mean, metric is not a real world unit? ;)

I stand corrected!  Metric or Imperial would be fine, but "none" could be the wrong option.
